# Handling empty cells when reading from textfile using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, parsing

I have a textfile that has the following format:

```
2018 150 03:10:00 cluster1  22.53  94.04   85532  73.19 134.53  123470   39209 mms1  
2018 150 03:15:00           23.02  92.58   85271  73.01 131.93  122216   39403 mms1  
2018 150 03:10:00 cluster2  22.93  97.33   86841  73.36 140.32  143174   39854 mms1
```

However, when I read the textfile using the following piece of code:

```
data = pd.read_csv("data.txt", sep='\\s+', header=None,
names=\["year", "day", "time", "sat", "GM_Lat", "GM_Long", "Radius", "Trace_GM_Lat", "Trace_GM_Long", "ArcLen", "Dist", "Lead_Sat"\])

data.fillna("", inplace=True)
```

The empty cells such as the one in row 2 and column 4 is not handled correctly, instead the value that is next to it is added there (23.02). Any tips on how to handle this?

I have tried using the fwf method instead of csv, but did not succeed. Not sure how to apply it here since the widths of the columns is changing in the textfile due to higher and lower values. I have tried this aswell:

```
    colnames = ["year", "day", "time", "sat", "GM_Lat", "GM_Long", "Radius", "Trace_GM_Lat",
                              "Trace_GM_Long", "ArcLen", "Dist", "Lead_Sat"]
    colspecs = [(0, 4), (4, 7), (7, 15), (15, 22), (22, 30), (30, 38), (38, 46), (46, 54), (54, 62), (62, 70), (70, 78),
                (78, 86)]

    # read the data into a pandas DataFrame
    data = pd.read_fwf('data.txt', names=colnames, colspecs=colspecs, header=None)

    data.fillna("", inplace=True)
```

and this:

```
data = pd.read_fwf("data.txt", header=None, na_values="",
                       names=["year", "day", "time", "sat", "GM_Lat", "GM_Long", "Radius", "Trace_GM_Lat", "Trace_GM_Long", "ArcLen", "Dist", "Lead_Sat"], keep_default_na=False)

data.fillna("", inplace=True)
```

This last one worked really good but on the last columns something happened and it did not work. I only get nan and empty cells for column Trace_GM_Long and forward. All help is appreciated!

Comment: The problem is that `\s+` as a separator treat this empty value as part for the separator. You could trying using ` +` for the `sep` to catch only spaces, and use `tab` to represent empty value.

Comment: Do you mean like this @sagi?
data = pd.read_csv("data.txt", sep=' +', header=None, na_values="\t",
                       names=[...]
It did not work, but maybe I misunderstood.

Comment: Yes for the `sep`. No need for the `na_values='\t'`. I meant that you need to modify the txt file, and put a tab every place that represent a missing value. You need some way to differentiate between space and an empty value and this is one way to achieve this.

Comment: Alright thank you @sagi! The empty values seem to be exactly 3 tabs I just noticed, is that of any use? Simply because there a quite a lot of rows with empty values and would be very time consuming to modify the entire textfile manually.

Comment: It depends, are they a tab character or a 4 space characters?

Comment: Seems to me it is 4 space characters @sagi